# Call super in module-defined method from inheriting class

Tags: ruby

The title kind of sucks, so take this code instead:

```
module MyModule
  def foo
    puts "Foo!"
    super if defined?(super)
  end
end

class MyClass
  include MyModule
end

class MySubclass < MyClass
  include MyModule
end
```

If I call the following, "Foo!" prints once.

```
MySubclass.new.foo
# Foo!
# => nil
```

I'd like it to print twice, by calling the `MySubclass` one first, then the `MyClass` one second by doing `super`.

The `MySubclass` ancestry looks like:

```
[MySubclass, MyClass, MyModule, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

I might be misunderstanding how Ruby does class, method ancestry, so if this isn't the way to do it, is there another clever way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**: Okay, sounds like I need to give a more useful use case. Let's say the module does something like ActiveRecord or Mongoid where you declare an attribute.

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    attr_reader :fields
    def field(name)
      (@fields ||= []) << name.to_sym
    end
  end
end
```

Then you use that to declare a field on class and subclass:

```
class MyClass
  include MyModule
  field(:a)
end

class MySubclass < MyClass
  include MyModule
  field(:b)
end
```

If you invoked `MySubclass.fields`, I don't want it to return `[:b]` I'd like it to return `[:a, :b]`, by calling `fields` on its parent class and concatenating its own onto the result.

Comment: The module is only included once: [“Ruby’s default implementation is to add the constants, methods, and module variables of this module to _mod_ if this module has not already been added to _mod_ **or one of its ancestors.**”](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-append_features) What’s your use case, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What you're saying makes sense. But I'm still trying to figure out a clever way to get the behavior I want. I added another use case above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because these are class methods, you can kind of do an end-run around worrying about `super` by doing this:

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def fields
      (@fields || []) + (superlcass.respond_to?(:fields) ? superclass.fields : []) 
    end
    def field(name)
      (@fields ||= []) << name.to_sym
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is more or less exactly what I ended up doing.